# Efficient way to encode a dataframe into a tree-like, nested-if structure?

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, encoding, tree

Suppose I had a `pandas` dataframe that looked something like this:

```
 A   B   C   D   value
 1   4   6   9   100
 1   4   6   10  101
 1   5   7   9   100
 1   5   7   11  102
 1   5   8   10  105
```

That is, there are some identifying features whose combination uniquely identify a row, then some value. In this case there are 4 identifying features in `A, B, C, D` and the combination of the four values will be unique within the dataframe.

And I want to `print` the following nested `if` statement:

```
if A == 1
    if B == 4
        if C == 6
            if D == 9
                100
            if D == 10
                101
    if B == 5
        if C == 7
            if D == 9
                100
            if D == 11
                102
        if C == 8
            if D == 10
                105
```

What is an efficient (in terms of memory required to store the string) way to encode data with a variable number of identifiers `A, B, ...` into this format, assuming I know the identifying columns are already arranged in order of increasing cardinality?

`and` is also allowed, so I can also represent the tree like:

```
if A == 1
    if B == 4 and C == 6
        if D == 9
            100
        if D == 10
            101
    if B == 5
        if C == 7
            if D == 9
                100
            if D == 11
                102
        if C == 8 and D == 10
            105
```

Would be ecstatic about the latter, but a solution that achieves the former will already solve my problem!

Here is a sample `df` I cobbled together:

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
              'B': [4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5], 
              'C': [6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8], 
              'D': [9, 10, 9, 11, 10, 12, 12, 13, 15, 10, 9, 10, 9, 16, 17],
              'value': [100, 101, 100, 102, 105, 103, 103, 100, 101, 107, 102, 100, 111, 105, 109]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this isn't exactly what you asked for, but it I think its worth considering.

Maybe you could train a decision tree classifier. You could then export the tree and then write some custom code to convert a tree to if-statements, which should be straight-forward. Here is some code I was tinkering with:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree
from graphviz import Source
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
                     'B': [4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5], 
                     'C': [6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8], 
                     'D': [9, 10, 9, 11, 10, 12, 12, 13, 15, 10, 9, 10, 9, 16, 17], 
                     'value': [100, 101, 100, 102, 105, 103, 103, 100, 101, 107, 102, 100, 111, 105, 109]})


X = data[['A', 'B', 'C', "D"]]
Y = data["value"]

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)

# Display Tree
classes = Y.unique().astype(np.str)
Source( tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None, feature_names=X.columns, class_names=classes) )
```

Comment: interesting. thanks for the suggestion - I will try this out